# import/no-unresolved in Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: reactjs, bitbucket-pipelines, eslintrc

For my React app, my .env file has the following entry:

```
NODE_PATH=./src
```

This allows me to use absolute paths when importing packages.

In eslintrc.json, I have this configuration to handle eslint's import/no-unresolved rule:

```
"settings": { "import/resolver": { "node": { "paths": ["src"] } } },
```

This set up works in my local environment.

However, when I push my code to Bitbucket, the build fails with this message:

```
error Unable to resolve path to module 'components/Header/Header' import/no-unresolved
```

How should I set up Bitbucket Pipelines?

Comment: Ignore. It seems like my problem was with git. Git did not capture the case changes to the filename. Keeping the question here since it might help someone anyway.